# Set marker on Google Map when changing a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need some help regarding the Google Maps API. I was able to initialize the map. Now I want to add some markers to it.
I have a set of checkboxes (they are called "networks"). Each checkbox has a hidden longitude and latitude field. If the checkbox is checked, a marker should be displayed on the map 
I managed to do this with the detour, of clicking on the map. But I want to trigger the creation of new markers on change of the checkbox.

Here is how it works, when I click on the map the markers appear:

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 6,
    center: {lat: 48.7791, lng: 9.0367}
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {

    //Get all checked Networks
    var checked_network = $( ".checkbox-network:checked" );
    checked_network.each(function(){
      network_id = $( this ).data("network-id");
      //Get the hidden location longitudes and latitudes for each checked network element
      network_locations_latitude = $(".location_latitude_network_"+network_id).val();
      network_locations_longitude = $(".location_longitude_network_"+network_id).val();
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(network_locations_latitude,network_locations_longitude),
          map: map
       });
    });
  });
}
```

Here is how I try to get it to work, with clicking on the checkboxes. Unfortunately nothing happens. The `marker` object shows up in the JavaScript console, but on the map no markers appear.

```
$(document).on('change','.checkbox-network', function() {
    var checked_network = $( ".checkbox-network:checked" );
    checked_network.each(function(){
      network_id = $( this ).data("network-id");

      //Get the hidden location longitudes and latitudes for each checked network element
      network_locations_latitude = $(".location_latitude_network_"+network_id).val();
      network_locations_longitude = $(".location_longitude_network_"+network_id).val();
      console.log(network_id + " - " + network_locations_latitude);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(network_locations_latitude,network_locations_longitude),
          map: map,
          title: "test"
       });
      console.log(marker);
    });
});
```

What am I missing? How can I show the markers in the google-map with the `onchange`event of the checkboxes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to initialize map variable globally. Currently scope of map variable only available inside initMap() function.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 6,
        center: {lat: 48.7791, lng: 9.0367}
});
$(document).on('change','.checkbox-network', function() {
   var checked_network = $( ".checkbox-network:checked" );
   checked_network.each(function(){
    network_id = $( this ).data("network-id");
       //Get the hidden location longitudes and latitudes for each checked network element
    network_locations_latitude = $(".location_latitude_network_"+network_id).val();
    network_locations_longitude = $(".location_longitude_network_"+network_id).val();
    console.log(network_id + " - " + network_locations_latitude);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(network_locations_latitude,network_locations_longitude),
              map: map,
              title: "test"
    });
    console.log(marker);
   });
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't this keep resetting the map? You basically call and create a `new google.maps.Map()`; The new map won't have the previous added objects including markers.

Comment: Thank you. I now understand my mistake and fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

In the second snippet of your code, the `map` isn't defined because it's been defined in the scope of `initMap()`. I wonder why Google doesn't throw any errors.

change your initMap like below; move the `map` object to the global scope to be accessible from all scope (I always use this for my own projects)

```
initMap() {

  window.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 6,
    center: {lat: 48.7791, lng: 9.0367}
  });

}
```

Here you should be more logical with the name `map`, so replace it with another name to avoid further conflicts.

Comment: Thank you. I now understand my mistake and fixed it.